# I need to find all predictors(p-value < 0.05) from my dataset using loops. Is there any way to do it?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I am new to R and I am using glm() function to fit a logistic model. I have 5 columns. I need to find all possible predictors using a loop based on their p-values(less than 0.05).
My dataset has 40,000 entries which contains numerical and categorical variables and it looks more or less like this:

```
  "Age"   "Sex"     "Occupation"    "Education"   "Income"       
   50       Male      Farmer         High School    False
   30      Female      Maid          High School    False
   25       Male     Engineer        Graduate       True
```

The target variable "Income" denotes if the person earns more or less than 30K. If true means, they earn more than 30K and vice versa. I would like to find the predictor variables that can be used to predict the target using loops. Also, can I find the best 3 predictors based on their p-values?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you want to predict group membership (two groups based on income), you might want to look into statisticals methods like discriminant analysis instead of linear regression

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I would like to find the predictors using glm(Income ~. datatrain, family=binomial) .

Comment: please post a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question you are looking into a way of test univariable models given your dataframe (i am in fact in doubt if you want to test every combination of these variables including cross variation)

My suggestion is to use purrr::map function and create list for every column. Check the following example based on your information:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

## Sample data
df <- data.frame(
  Age = rnorm(n = 40000, 
              mean = mean(c(50,30,25)), 
              sd(c(50,30,25))),
  
  Ocupation = sample(x = c("Farmer", "Maid", "Engineer"), 
                     size = 40000, 
                     replace = TRUE),
  Education = sample(x = c("High School", "Graduate", "UnderGraduate"), 
                     size = 40000, 
                     replace = TRUE),
  Income = as.logical(rbinom(40000, 1, 0.5))
  )


## Split dataframe into lists
list_df <- Map(cbind, split.default(df[-4], names(df)[-4]))
list_df <- lapply(list_df, cbind, "target" = df[4])

## Use map to fit a model for each list
list_models <- map(.x = list_df,
    .f = ~glm(Income ~ ., data = .x, family = binomial))
```

You can call each model using list_models[i].

Now addressing the second part of your question concerning p-values. Given that each project is unique and so are their metrics i suggest you double check you usage of p-values. Granted, they are important, but they provid you a probability of acceptance given a specific statistic test and treshold which depends on context. It is a fundamental tool of statistical quality and decision (not only about t-test,  but f-test and hence forward). But for ranking ? hmm i would say is a litle odd. But just saying :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @pedro magalhaes. I will try this out. :)
Also, as part of the problem statement that I have, the threshold value for which the predictor variable should fall under is 0.05. It'd be great if I can find using p-value.

Cheers :)